# This e-mail filter won't work?

Tags: php, html

I made this filter to censor out e-mails that has cursing in them. Code is as follows:

```html
foreach ($badWords as $word) {
if (strpos($msg,$word) !== false) {
   $mail=false;
   echo"Please do not curse in your messages. We are a child-friendly community.";
}
}
```

Now the problem is, no matter what message I input, it will give out the 'pls dont cursz' message.

It's just a sector, not the full page. `$msg` is the message, title and message combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>It seems working if you close between brackets the if statement.</s>
your code seems working fine, maybe the problem was elsewhere.

<s>`if ((strpos($msg,$word)) !== false)`</s>

By the way
note that your script will echo that string for each bad word found.
Maybe something like this is better :

```
$msg = 'stupid is a bad word';
$counter = 0;
$badWords =['dumb','stupid'];

foreach ($badWords as $word) {
 if ((strpos($msg,$word)) !== false) {
        $counter++;
 }
}

if ($counter == 0){
   echo 'good  guy';
}else{
   $mail=false;
   echo"Please do not curse in your messages. We are a child-friendly community.";
}
```

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab577bd292b845dae6ea0f83a48464f0cb848062)
[demo2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/145804580cb83651dea36ba7a4f9e6965c4c9231)